# How to retrieve a json object from a sharepoint list

Tags: javascript, xml, json, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am created myself a custom list with sharepoint 2007, which is exactly the same as any excel spreadsheet in effect.

I was told that i can get this out all of the information as a json or XML object. I don't have access to the file system, only to sharepoint web interface.

Can i just use a url and do my normal `getJson`?

```
    $.getJSON("http://somesharepointurl.asp?get=json",function(results){
        console.info(results);
        $.each(results, function(){

        });
    });
```

Or is there no way of doing this without writing some backend service?

**Edit**

```
https://someserver/sites/DisasterRecovery/eventmgmt/DRR/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={B0ACA997-8A41-498B-97FE-B276D48F64D7}&XMLDATA=TRUE
```

I have tried this... it gave me this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Fri, 14 Dec 2012 11:41:55 GMT
Connection: close
```

No idea what to look for whatsoever i'm afraid :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the simple answer:

[jquery.SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/releases/view/81401)

you will need jQuery 1.4.2+ to run this but its fantastic :) It has many more method's than just getting XML or json back.

```
 var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy</Query>";
 $().SPServices({
     operation:"GetListItems",
     async:false,
     listName:"Home Page Carousel",
     CAMLViewFields:"<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='userName'/><FieldRef Name='userDepartment'/><FieldRef Name='message'/></ViewFields>",
     CAMLQuery:query,
     CAMLRowLimit:10,
     completefunc:function (xData, Status) {
     console.info(xData);
     console.info(Status);
         $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
             var $this = $(this);
             $this.attr("ows_message")//retrieve list data here and do stuff here
         });
     }
 });
```

This will return you a lovely chunk of XML .

Comment: Yes, Marc's done a great job making middle tier customization feasible for front-end developers and power-users. The nearly sole viable generic option for SharePoint 2007.

Comment: exactly! I think people should be +1'ing this so other users believe it :p

Answer (score 3):

1. SharePoint 2007 doesn't provide you with JSON formatted results, only SOAP/XML web services and the URL Protocol you refer to  in the update
2. Make sure you append the /_vti_bin part to the address of the correct subsite, rather than the library (although if you made this error, you'd get 404)

Comment: So something like.... `sites/gskglobal/mcLaren-partnership/Lists/Home%20Page%20Carousel`? for replacing the _vti_bin?

Comment: See Shawn's answer about SharePoint 2010 OData REST service and yours accepted about jQuery.SPServices. Those should suffice.

Comment: The correct one would end before "/Lists" - in your case, sites/gskglobal/mcLaren-partnership/_vti_bin/... And jQuery.SPServices figures it out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, in sharepoint 2010 try use the OData like these : `http://webname/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/listname` , and the feature of filter and sort is same as standard OData, refference can be found here: http://www.odata.org/documentation

Comment: Although not in the header of the question, the topic starter was explicit in defining that their environment is SharePoint 2007. This response is helpful for search-users but those should not be misled. There is no such capability in that version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add &Query=* to the URL query string